# Show Rows as Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I havent worked with Pivot. Not sure if pivot is the right thing to use. Is it possible to show this data:

```
-------------------
| Name     | Code |
-------------------
|Test A    | 1    |
|Test B    | 2    |
|Test C    | 3    |
-------------------
```

In this format:

```
------------------------------
| Customer | Fleet | Account |
------------------------------
|Test A    |Test B |Test C   |
------------------------------
```

If Code is 1 it is Customer.  If Code is 2 it is Fleet.  If Code is 3 it is Account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with `pivot`, when you are dealing with translating the columns into rows you will still need to utilize an aggregate. The `pivot` has three primary pieces:

1. Group
2. Spread
3. Aggregate

---

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (name VARCHAR(255), code INT);

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES ('Test A', 1), ('Test B', 2), ('Test C', 3);

SELECT [1] AS 'Customer', [2] AS 'Fleet', [3] AS 'Account'
FROM @table
PIVOT(MAX(name) FOR code IN (
            [1],
            [2],
            [3]
            )) pvt;
```

In the working example above we see the grouping as `Name` and we spread the results of `code` across three columns with hard coded values. The aggregate is based on the `MAX` value of `name`, this is what let's us pivot the row by pivoting on a group with a max value that would only return one row.

Now if you want to create this dynamically vs hardcoding, you'll need to look into dynamic sql.

Here's an article on dynamic pivot sql on [MS SQL Tips by Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/)